# Prove that $xf(x)$ is convex.

Tags: convex-analysis

Suppose that $f:[0,1] \mapsto [0,\infty)$ is an increasing function with $f(0) = 0$. Then, is it true that $x\mapsto xf(x)$ is convex? It appears to be the case when $f$ is convex. However, I couldn't prove it for general $f$. I also couldn't find a counterexample. Any ideas?

Comment: $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln\left(1+2x^2\right)}{5+3x^3}$ is a function monotonically increasing on $[0,1]$ but $g(x)=xf(x)$ is not a convex function on $[0,1]$. I think it is possible to find simpler counterexamples.

Comment: Thanks @Antonio, I've just found a simpler counterexample ( f(x) = 1-exp(-kx), k>2 ) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1060458/960429

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = 1-\exp(-kx)$ for $k>2$ is a counterexample.